# Can I get specific "dl" i.e. at First or Second index out of many identified by a CSS Selector in my App

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I'm trying to automate a functionality using selenium in my Application Chrome browser. It's an SVG graph based page and shows details upon mouse over it. And this is identifiable with a CSS selector which is returning more than one matching elements(i.e. 6-7 **dl** , these dls has few child tags then internally containing the values I need to verify -as attached), now my need to select them one by one at a time and verify text of them(which displayed on mouse over). 
I got to know on google how to read nth-child from **dl** but not getting a way to select particular **dl** at first place.
For example-
my selector is: .d3-tip.n>dl
if I use -.d3-tip.n>dl>dt:nth-child(odd): its giving me all the attributes of dt.. ie 6 values but I nedd values only from fst dl.
Similarly.d3-tip.n>dl>dd:nth-child(even) returning the 6 values of respected dds..
In Actual my app has only one dl (on UI) but don't know why it displaying 6 in DOM...

**Plz refer attachment and HTML** for a clear understanding of DOM

```html
<div class="d3-tip n" style="position: absolute; top: 44.5px; opacity: 0; pointer-events: none; box-sizing: border-box; left: 515px;">
<dl style="width:335px">
<dt>Space Name:</dt>
<dd>Space</dd>
<dt>Property Type:</dt>
<dd>Office</dd>
<dt>Quoted Area:</dt>
<dd>444 sf</dd>
<dt>Space Usage:</dt>
<dd>Business Park,Commercial School</dd>
<dt>Space Status:</dt>
<dd>For Lease</dd>
<dt>Possession Status:</dt>
<dd>Vacant</dd>
</dl>
<span class="d3-tip__pin"/>
</div>
<div class="d3-tip n" style="position: absolute; top: 44.5px; opacity: 0; pointer-events: none; box-sizing: border-box; left: 515px;">
<dl style="width:335px">
<dt>Space Name:</dt>
<dd>Space</dd>
<dt>Property Type:</dt>
<dd>Office</dd>
<dt>Quoted Area:</dt>
<dd>444 sf</dd>
<dt>Space Usage:</dt>
<dd>Business Park,Commercial School</dd>
<dt>Space Status:</dt>
<dd>For Lease</dd>
<dt>Possession Status:</dt>
<dd>Vacant</dd>
</dl>
<span class="d3-tip__pin"/>
</div>
<--! and so on up to 6 blocks of dl
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: In the same way you use n to select the li, you could create a for loop and select a dl with n using the index of the for

Comment: Please add some of your attempts to your question...

Comment: [Don't do this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361474/should-we-display-a-warning-when-users-include-images/361481#361481). Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: @DebanjanB: Sure, Just added HTML and found it much easier than adding attachments..Thanks

Comment: @MosheSlavin: Tried adding few in question, I'm not familiar with CSS. I know in xpath how to get nth element out on many.. like: "(//* your xpath)[index]" but not sure in css..and unfortunately this element can't be clicked using xpath..

Comment: Is your expectation to get  first dl value or first dt of first dl or first dt and first dd of firsrt dl?

Comment: @Navarasu: Basically I need all dd values of 1st dl,so that I can match them with corresponding expected values.

Comment: @saTya: When you say- " In Actual my app has only one dl (on UI) but don't know why it displaying 6 in DOM.".. it seems to be an issue from Developer side, if there is only one graph on UI why you should see 6 containers for dl. check with your developer on this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I am not sure which of the elements you want...

So... here is a snip that should give you help.

A) with hovering.

B) with looping through the elements.

C) **Bonus** learn about `contains()` functionality of XPath...

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains


url = "http://your_url"
path_to_chromedriver = "C:\path_to_chromedriver"
chrome_options = Options()
#chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path_to_chromedriver,
                       chrome_options=chrome_options)
browser.get(url)
# list_of_dt_elements_to_hover = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'d3-tip')]//dl/dt")
list_of_dt_elements_to_hover = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[class='d3-tip n']//dl/dt")
list_of_dd_elements_to_hover = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'d3-tip')]//dl/dd")
hover = ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(list_of_dt_elements_to_hover[0])
hover.perform()
for dd_ele in list_of_dt_elements_to_hover:
    hover = ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(dd_ele)
    hover.perform()
    print(dd_ele.text)
for dd_ele in list_of_dd_elements_to_hover:
    hover = ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(dd_ele)
    hover.perform()
    print(dd_ele.text)
```

I hope you find this helpful!

Answer (score 2):

nth-child is to find the nth-child of any immediate parent element. In your HTML DOM, dd is single child element of each div.d3-tip element. The repetitive child is actually your div.d3tip for it immediate parent element

So your selector has to be written as below to get the first set of dd,

```
div.d3-tip:nth-child(1)>dl>dd
```

[image]

Getting the second selector also works. This is most important while writing css selector. The second nth has to work. :).
[image]

Comment: Thank you Navarasu, for explaining so nicely!